# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Example: table `Customer`. `CustomerName` column is `varchar(100)` and in stored procedure is also same size.

When I try to update a row by passing in `harry.smith@charterglobal.com`, it throws this error:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Column size is 100. Passed value is less then that, still I get this error - why?

Here passing email instead of name.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I am going to go with believing the error message here.

Comment: Are you sure it's this column? Unless you can provide an [MCVE] then we're basically just guessing or telling you to research the error...

Comment: yes, i verified with passing normal string it worked, when i passed "abcdefgh@qualitydistribution.com" it failed

Comment: Show us the stored procedure

Comment: Is there by any chance a **trigger** on that table, that might be making another `insert` into some other table and the error comes from that trigger??

Comment: What's a normal string exactly? How are you passing/executing it? Is there whitespace that exists somewhere.

Comment: it was just a update table procedure, no other code in that

Comment: Without the details of your table or a way to reproduce the outcome this question in unanswerable because given only the details in the question this not reproducible.

Comment: Are u using any temp table in the stored procedure which has different datalength than the original table you want to insert.

Comment: added stored procedure above @SeanLange

Comment: How have you determined that is the column that is the problem? Your "code" above is so generic it is really not demonstrating the issue at hand.

Comment: not using any temp table - @Sujatha

Comment: verified with passing normal string it worked, when i passed "abcdefgh@qualitydistribution.com" it failed  -  @Sean Lange

Comment: So provide the ddl of your table with some sample data. Then an update that reproduces the error. Because the description you keep saying happens is impossible. There is either something else in your update or a trigger on the table. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Actual column size is 100 in sql when the string length exceeds 30  this error is produced -@SeanLange

Comment: figured, error is with the triggers but code seems to be good, can you suggest, triggers updated above -@SeanLange

Comment: @Zr2271 I don't see the update with the trigger code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard correct answer here, but if you run sql server profiler, you should be able to find the offensive sql statement, and you can then figure it out.

Comment: figured it is with the trigger update but it seems to be good, no idea why it breaking over there -@jyao

Answer (score 0):

This is a long standing case where SQL Server has had a terrible error message for over decade and Microsoft has given nothing but excuses.

You will have to spend time to isolate the table, field and value involved because Microsoft fails to provide them in the error message.

Comment: i verified with passing normal string it worked, when i passed "abcdefgh@qualitydistribution.com" it failed  @brian

Comment: Your assuming the field. Check the stored procedure and see if the value is chopped up and placed elsewhere where it might overflow. Like a Firstname varchar(30) field that gets everything up to the first space would truncate on that value. As others mentioned check for triggers etc as well.

Comment: Yes this has been a long running joke to say the least. It is painfully obvious at the time it happens that the engine knows exactly which column and table. Not reporting that in the error message is just infuriating!!!

Comment: figured, error is with the triggers but code seems to be good, can you suggest, triggers updated above - @Brian